# Soap XML response to Array in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, soap

I am trying to read ASP web service via PHP. Web service is working fine and it returns a XML with soap headers. I tried to read that xml using normal way which use to read xml in php. But since there is additional soap tags in xml it fails to read.

Here is my soap response.
I need to put this XML to array using PHP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
    <SayHelloResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SayHelloResult>
    <Students xmlns="">
    <St>
    <name>Sanath</name>
    <age>20</age>
    </St>
    <St>
    <name>Mahela</name>
    <age>21</age>
    </St>
    </Students>
    </SayHelloResult>
    </SayHelloResponse>
    </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: And what is your normal way?

Comment: I need to put this soap xml response to PHP array. I have tried to do , but the problem is it is not working because of soap envelope (soap markup tags). without those headers, it is working fine. Please help.